# Trying sql injection gives ORA-00911: invalid character with jpa getSingleResult() method(Only for learning purpose)

Tags: java, security, jpa, sql-injection

In my application i am creating a sql query by appending parameters manually in the main query.

```
String query = "select count(*) from user where name = '" + name + "'";
```

And then executing this query as:

```
Query myQuery = em.createNativeQuery(query );
BigDecimal count = (BigDecimal) myQuery.getSingleResult();
```

Now i am passing "x';drop table user;--" value from ui and my query is also forming as expected. The query i am getting is

```
select count(*) from user where name = 'x';drop table user;--name';
```

But while executing i am getting ORA-00911: invalid character exception.

So if i cannot put special characters in query through jpa than how using manually appended query is vulnerable to sql injection else what mistake i am doing above?

Comment: i believe comments in SQL have to have some whitespace in front. So instead of `;--` try `; --`

Comment: I recall that oracle driver doesn't like ';' character at the end of the query string.

Comment: @SourceOverflow: No there is nothing like that. But i tried that as well.

Comment: @Juan So here i cannot close the previous statement? If so oracle should be sql injection safe.

Comment: I got this example (select * from app_users where userid ='JUDY' and userpass = 'somepass' or '1' = '1') from http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_injections_attacks.htm, it is sqlinjection but doesn't use ';'

Comment: @juan yes that is fine but for me also query is forming fine problem is jpa is not executing it. You can refer the link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: If you are executing a raw query (not a prepared statement) with the example it should run with no issue because there isn't anything strange in it.

Comment: @Juan yes even i was expecting the same but its throwing ORA-00911: invalid character exception.

Comment: Instead of getSingleResult, use List results = query.getResultList(); The example should retrieve more than one result

Comment: @juan So what will happen with that? My query is returning only count i.e 1 result.

Comment: When you run a native query, the query is passed to the driver. Your query has semicolons which oracle driver doesn't like in query strings. That doesn't mean it is sql injection proof. The example I gave shows you how to form a query where the expect value is a password and instead of that any text is provided + ' OR 1=1'  which will be true for all the records of tha table, hence returning all the table contents. So for this kind of query the expected is more than one result.

Comment: @Juan So you mean to say that we cannot close any sql statement in oracle from ui? That means we  cannot run batch sql statement from ui we can only modify existing statement?

Comment: I was refering to ending query strings in java with a semicolon. Just try it with and without and you'll see.

Comment: I tried all the possible combinations. But still not working.